# Access nested array, where depth is unknown until runtime in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, types, tree, nested

Example:

```
array = [ [ [ [ ["foo"] ] ] ] ]
array[0][0][0][0][0] == "foo" # => true
```

In this case I knew that the depth of the array is 5, so that I could use
`array[0][0][0][0][0]` to access what's inside of it.
My question is: How can I access (write to it) an element inside of a nested array in Ruby if I have the `depth = ?`, where `?` is different every time the program runs. (I assume that every array has only one sub-array).

Answer (score 3):

You need a recursive function:

```
def innermost(x)
  (x.is_a? Array) ? innermost(x[0]) : x
end

array = [ [ [ [ ["foo"] ] ] ] ]
innermost(array)
# => "foo"
```

**UPDATE**

The updated version returns the innermost array instead of the element of the array.

```
def innermost(x)
  (x[0].is_a? Array) ? innermost(x[0]) : x
end

array = [ [ [ [ ["foo"] ] ] ] ]
a = innermost(array)  # => ["foo"]
a[0] = 'bar'
array
# => [[[[["bar"]]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this already helps me. Unfortunately, I need to put something inside the array that contains "foo". So how can I _write_ to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use flatten if the array contains only one data.

```
array = [ [ [ [ ["foo"] ] ] ] ]
array.flatten[0]
 => "foo"
```

Comment: The OP wants to change its value.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit:** I was trying to be too cute, and it bit me. Originally I suggested two methods that determined the number of levels by using `array.to_s[/\[+/].size`. One of the methods used `eval` to convert a string to the output array.  @FrederickCheung pointed out two flaws (thanks, Frederick), which you can see in the comments. If you'd like to see my original answer, you can look at the edits, of course. I have now edited to suggest a more conventional variant of the first method I originally propopsed. **tidE**

Here's a non-recursive method.

```
def replace_foo(array, val) 
  a = array
  nbr_levels = (1..Float::INFINITY).find { |i| !(a=a.first).is_a? Array }
  nbr_levels.times.reduce(val) { |a,_| [a] }
end

array = [ [ [ [ ["foo"] ] ] ] ]
  #=> [[[[["foo"]]]]]

replace_foo(array, { our_dog: "Diva", our_cat: "Teagan" })
  #=> [[[[[{:our_dog=>"Diva", :our_cat=>"Teagan"}]]]]]
```

Comment: The array to_s version would produce incorrect results if the value was something that contained `[` when converted to a string

Comment: And your eval based replace method only works if the output of `to_s` is the ruby syntax for creating an object of that type (so replace_foo(array, "exit")) wouldn't work)

Comment: Oh, darn, but thanks, @FrederickCheung. I understand the `eval` problem, but not your first comment. Can you give an example?

Comment: For example `array = [[[["foo[]"]]]]`

Comment: Actually that's wrong - the output of inspect would have to start with a [

Comment: @FrederickCheung, but the innermost object cannot be array, as that would make its level ambiguous.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an array. For a contrived example try a instance of this class: `class X; def inspect; '['; end; end`

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. If `inspect` were redefined--which could happen--there could be a problem. Can the problem occur any other way?